# Excel to Json converter in JAVA

Tags: java, json, language-agnostic, jackson, apache-poi

Am trying to covert the excel data into JSON format. And i am successful upto converting excel data by reading the rows and columns and set the data to list and then converting that List to JSON format.

[image]

[image]

But, I stuck in next level of JSON where the format will be like
[image]

Here is the code which iam using, But not yet started how to make that nested data like 3 columns data should come in one array like the above image.

**Pojo class**:

```
public class Products implements Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name="ID")
private String id;

@Column(name="PRODUCTID")
private String productId;

@Column(name="NAMEID")
private String nameId;

@Column(name="NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name="P_DESC")
private String desc;

@Column(name="DIMENSION")
private String dimension;

@Column(name="CATEGORY")
private String category;

@Column(name="SUB_CATEGORY")
private String subcategory;

@Column(name="CATEGORYID")
private String categoryId;

@Column(name="SUBCATEGORYID")
private String subcategoryId;

@Column(name="TAGS")
private String tags;

@Column(name="DESIGNER")
private String designer;

@Column(name="CURR")
private String curr;

@Column(name="POPULARITY")
private String popularity;

@Column(name="RELEVANCE")
private String relevance;

@Column(name="SHORTLISTED")
private String shortlisted;

@Column(name="LIKES")
private String likes;

@Column(name="CREATE_String")
private String createDt;

@Column(name="PAGEID")
private String pageId;

@Column(name="STYLENAME")
private String styleName;

@Column(name="STYLEID")
private String styleId;

@Column(name="PRICERANGE")
private String priceRange;

@Column(name="PRICEID")
private String priceId;

@Column(name="DEFAULT_PRICE")
private String defaultPrice;

@Column(name="DEFAULT_MATERIAL")
private String defaultMaterial;

@Column(name="DEFAULT_FINISH")
private String defaultFinish;
/* setters and getters */
}
```

**ExceltoJsonConverter class**:

```
public static void uploadXLS(MultipartFile file, Document doc)
    throws IOException {

Products products = new Products();

List<Products> productsList = new ArrayList<Products>();

logger.info("uploadExcel method");
HSSFWorkbook wb = null;
try {

     wb= new HSSFWorkbook(file.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("workbook: "+wb);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        System.out.println("worksheet: "+sheet);
        HSSFRow row;

        Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                products = new Products();
                Row nextRow = iterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
                 Cell cell = cellIterator.next(); 
                    Iterator cells = nextRow.cellIterator();

                        cell=(HSSFCell) cells.next();

                        if (cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                        {
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+" ");
                        }
                        else if(cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                        {
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+" ");
                        }
                        else if(HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){
                            Date date = HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        } else
                        {
                            //U Can Handel Boolean, Formula, Errors
                        }

                        products.setId(new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(0)));
                        products.setProductId(new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(1)));
                        products.setNameId(new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(2)));
                        products.setName(new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(3)));
                        products.setDesc(new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(4)));
                        products.setDimension(new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(5)));
                        products.setCategory(new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(6)));
                        products.setSubcategory((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(7))));
                        products.setCategoryId(new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(8)));
                        products.setSubcategoryId((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(9))));
                        products.setTags((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(10))));
                        products.setDesigner((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(11))));
                        products.setCurr((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(12))));
                        products.setPopularity((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(13))));
                        products.setRelevance((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(14))));
                        products.setShortlisted((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(15))));
                        products.setLikes((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(16))));
                        products.setCreateDt((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(17))));
                        products.setPageId((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(18))));
                        products.setStyleName((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(19))));
                        products.setStyleId((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(20))));
                        products.setPriceRange((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(21))));
                        products.setPriceId((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(22))));
                        products.setDefaultPrice((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(23))));
                        products.setDefaultMaterial((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(24))));
                        products.setDefaultFinish((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(25))));

                        Map<String, String> inputMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        inputMap.put("name", "Java2Novice");
                        inputMap.put("site", "http://java2novice.com");
                        productsList.add(products);
                    System.out.println(productsList);
                

                     
           // JSON CONVERTER
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    System.out.println("productsList: "+products);
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
      Date date = new Date();
      String location = dateFormat.format(date);
      System.out.println("productsList final: "+products);

       // Convert object to JSON string and save into file directly
       mapper.writeValue(new File("D:\\"+location+"mygubbi.json"), productsList);
        // Convert object to JSON string and save into file directly
        mapper.writeValue(new File("D:\\products.json"), productsList);
        
        // Convert object to JSON string
        String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(productsList);
        System.out.println("JsonInString " +jsonInString);

        // Convert object to JSON string and pretty print
        jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                .writeValueAsString(products);
        System.out.println("Final Json" +mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                .writeValueAsString(products));
        mapper.writeValue(new File("D:\\productsJson.json"), jsonInString);


        }
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {


}
}
```

Please suggest me how to approach to get multiple columns data in Json format as shown below
[image]

A BIG Thank you in advance... Hoping anyone can make my day today :)

Comment: I have deleted my answer. It is not clear what your concrete problem is. Try to reduce your question to the essential and do not omit important information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too faced this type of scenario. You Just create A class with the fields which you having in the second sheet. 
For ex:

```
public class Somename{

private String abc;
private String xyz;
// getters and setters
}
```

In your pojo class define an array

```
private Somename some[];
```

Goto exceltoJson converter class.Try to create Hash map and fetch the details which u need in that sheet. That's it...

```
    public static Map getImgs(HSSFWorkbook wb) {

   Map hm1 = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Somename>>();
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(2);
    Iterator<Row> iterator= sheet.iterator();
    ArrayList<Somename> al = new ArrayList<Somename>();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = iterator.next();

        String sno = new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(row.getCell(0));


        if (hm1.get(sno) == null) {
            hm1.put(sno, new ArrayList());
        }

        String some= new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(row
                .getCell(1));

        Somename img1 = new Somename(some);
        System.out.println(img1);

        ArrayList r = (ArrayList) hm1.get(sno);
        r.add(img1);

    }
    return hm1;
    }
```

Then add this uploadXLS,

```
  ArrayList<Somename> al = (ArrayList<Somename>) hm1.get(id_prod);
                        Somename[] ar = new Images[al.size()];

                        products.setSome(al.toArray(imgfar));
```

May be this will help you.