# How can i convert fetched data to JSON using java

Tags: java, json, excel

I have successfully fetched data from excel sheet and now i want to convert the fetched data into JSON format. In specific format. How can i do further conversion part ?

[image: Excel Sheet VIEW]

The JSON format should be:

> {   Machine: M/C1,   Time: 12:00 PM,   Status: Working,}, {  Machine:
>   M/C2,  Time: 12:00PM,  Status: Working}, } ......}

Code which i have written to fetch data from excel sheet:

```
try {
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("F:\\software\\list.xls"));
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow row;
        HSSFCell cell;

        int rows; // No of rows
        rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

        int cols = 0; // No of columns
        int tmp = 0;


        for(int i = 0; i < 10 || i < rows; i++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(i);
            if(row != null) {
                tmp = sheet.getRow(i).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
                if(tmp > cols) cols = tmp;
            }
        }

        for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(r);
            if(row != null) {
                for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                    cell = row.getCell((short)c);
                    if(cell != null) {
                        // Your code here
                        System.out.println(cell);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You pick one of the dozens of Java JSON parsers/formatters (Jackson, GSon, Json Simple, whatever), read the documentation, and do what it tells.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw this question a few days back. EDIT: it was a similar one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866022/copying-excel-data-to-text-file-java-poi

Comment: **(1)** https://github.com/nullpunkt/excel-to-json/blob/master/src/main/java/net/nullpunkt/exceljson/convert/ExcelToJsonConverter.java   **(2)** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794684/excel-to-json-converter-in-java

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create a POJO class for the JSON entries, e.g.:

```
public class MachineData {
    private String machine;
    private String time;
    private String status;

    public MachineData(String m, String t, String s) {
        this.machine = m;
        this.time = t;
        this.status = s;
    }

    //+ getters, setters
}
```

Then create `MachineData` objects from the data you extracted from Excel. Put them in a list, then you can use [Jackson](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/) or [GSON](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) to convert the list into JSON.

```
// create a list of MachineData objects:
List<MachineData> list = new LinkedList<>();

// then when you go through Excel rows:
    String machine = ... // parse from Excel
    String time = ... // parse from Excel
    String status = ... // parse from Excel

    // build a MachineData object
    MachineData md = new MachineData(machine, time, status);

    // and add it to the list:    
    list.add(md);

// after you finished with the Excel part
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(list); // here you have the JSON in a string
```

Comment: can u please explain the list part here,, hoe it works,, a simple sample will work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Gson` (if you don't need high performance) or `Jackson` (if you care about performance).

Add gson as dependecy to your project. If you use Gradle just add this line to build.gradle `dependecies` section:

```
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.1'
```

Or check other build systems examples [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.1)

With Gson everything is quite simple. Declare a class for your object:

```
public class MachineStatus {
    @SerializedName("Machine")
    String machine;
    @SerializedName("Time")
    String time;
    @SerializedName("Status")
    String status;
}
```

Then prepare a list of such objects

```
    ArrayList<MachineStatus> statuses = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        row = sheet.getRow(r);
        if(row != null) {
            for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                cell = row.getCell((short)c);
                if(cell != null) {
                    // Your code here
                    System.out.println(cell);
                    MachineStatus status = new MachineStatus();
                    status.machine = cell.getMachine(); // change this part to use correct method that will fetch data from cell
                    status.time = cell.getTime(); // same here
                    status.status = cell.getStatus(); // same here
                    statuses.add(status);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setPrettyPrinting() // comment this out if you need to save bandwidth;
            .create();

    // Prints Json array string
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(statuses));
```

More on [gson and collections of objects](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types).

Comment: I m getting error: SerializedName cannot be resolved to a type,, in eclipse. How to resolve :(

Comment: Had you added gson dependency to your project? Which dependecy manager do you use, e.g. gradle / maven?

Comment: maven,, <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

Comment: try version `2.8.1` — this one `<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: great,, 2.8.1 worked, no errors :) I have created further 3 getters

Comment: @BleedCode Glad for you :) I can recommend you to switch to `kotlin`. You won't need to bother with getters :)